# Permission denied when I use mysql_connet through nginx but command line runs normally

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, centos, mariadb

My environment:

CentOS 6.6

Nginx 1.7.10 with mod_security, naxsi, ngx_pagespeed modules

PHP 5.6.5

Mariadb 10.0.16

SeLinux close

```
setenforce 0
```

My test code:

```
<?php
/*
** Connect to database:
*/

// connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','my pass')
       or die('Could not connect to the server! ' . mysql_error());

var_dump($con);
exit;
```

That's it.

And when I use firefox to run this script

The result is "Could not connect to the server! Permission denied"

The nginx error.log is

2015/02/18 23:26:33 [error] 1532#0: *68 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Permission denied in /var/www/nginx/aa.php on line 9" while reading response header from upstream, client: client ip, server: localhost, request: "GET /test-sql-injection.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "server ip"

But when I use command line to run this script

```
php aa.php
```

The result is

```
resource(5) of type (mysql link)
```

It is success to connect to maria db...

The mysql.sock file permission is

In /tmp

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql  mysql    25 2015-02-18 21:20 mysql.sock -> /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

In /var/lib/mysql

```
srwxrwxrwx.  1 mysql mysql        0 2015-02-18 23:03 mysql.sock
```

all command is run as root

and when I use another user to run php command

still get Permission denied error message!

which file's permission wrong?

======

/var/lib/mysql dir permission is 700

so it cause permission denied problem....

Answer (score 0):

php-cgi and php-cli are not using the same php.ini file.
Compare both file, maybe you have a difference

Comment: php -i | grep php.ini
=> /etc/php5.6.5/php.ini
and <?php phpinfo();
show that it is the same php.ini

Comment: Have you looked into /var/log/mysql.log (or equivalent file for mariadb) ?

Answer (score -1):

Check full path to socket file.
every directory in the path to socket must have eXecute permission for webserver user.
e.g. /var/ or /var/lib/ or /var/lib/mysql/ could have chmod 700 when it must have chmod 711.

Note that making more permissive chmod could lead to security issues. I suggest you moving `mysql.sock` into world-accessible-by-default directory such as /tmp